# ErrorInfo in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

Is there any way in JavaFX to prompt and handle errors similar to org.​jdesktop.​swingx.​error.​ErrorInfo class ?

Please let me know if any way available in JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

An [ErrorInfo dialog handler](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/error/ErrorInfo.html) is not part of the core JavaFX 2.2 platform.  You will have to develop such a handler yourself.

There are a couple of existing JavaFX dialog projects around.  If you wish, you could base your work off of one of these projects and contribute back such a dialog handler - [JavaFX UI controls sandbox](http://fxexperience.com/2012/10/announcing-the-javafx-ui-controls-sandbox/), [jfxtras](http://jfxtras.org/) and [MonologFX](https://blogs.oracle.com/javajungle/entry/monologfx_floss_javafx_dialogs_for).